# Linq OrderBy then GroupBy - group by unexpectedly changes order of list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

When I run this expression i can see that the list order is correctly in sequence by the highest ActionId's

```
var list = db.Actions.Where(z => z.RunId
   == RunId).OrderByDescending(w => 
    w.ActionId).ToList();
```

I only want to select the highest ActionId's of **each** ActionName so I now do:

```
var list = db.Actions.Where(z => z.RunId
 == RunId).OrderByDescending(w => 
 w.ActionId).GroupBy(c => new
         {
            c.ActionName,
            c.MachineNumber,
         })
         .Select(y => 
      y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

When I look at the contents of list, it hasn't selected the ActionName/MachineNumber with the highest ActionId, which I assumed would be the case by ordering then using FirstOrDefault().

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I want to group the records by the ActionName and MachineId, and then pick the record with the highest ActionId for each group

Comment: The title asks one thing but the question another. `GroupBy` does affect the order of results. In fact, `ORDER BY` in SQL can only appear *after* a `GROUP BY`. No matter what your ORM's query language is, in the end it's translated into SQL. That answers the title's question. The question text seems to be asking how to retrieve a single record per group though

Comment: If you want  the maximum ActionID per group, use `Max()`, eg `.GroupBy(..).Select(g=>new {g.Key,MaxID=g.Max(a=>ActionId)})`. There's no need for ordering. If you want to retrieve the  record with the maximum ID per group though, the query is very different

Comment: I feel like if still not quite solved what you're trying to do. Some example input and expected output might help get you the answer you're after

Comment: Sorry i think i confused people with my title. What i was trying to say that i ordered the list but then the group by meant the FirstOrDefault() record was not the ones i was expecting. The solution offered has solved this. Thanks All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of grouping an ordered collection, group the collection first, and then select the record with the highest ID for each of the groups. `GroupBy` is not guaranteed to preserve the order in each group in LINQ to SQL - it depends on your database server.

```
var list = db.Actions.Where(z => z.RunId == RunId).GroupBy(c => new
                {
                    c.ActionName,
                    c.MachineNumber,
                })
                .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.ActionId).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Jamiec Won't that return the maximum action ID value, rather than the full record with the maximum action ID? I understood the requirement to be the latter.

Comment: I've just caught up with this answer ;) Was having a slow moment! Sorry it took me a while